# Laravel views folder structure for different designs

Tags: laravel

I need some help - I want to change the whole design of my website, but I want to have the option to switch back to the old design.

My current folder structure is:

```
resources/views/frontend/...
```

I want to have the following folder structure:

```
resources/views/frontend/v1/...
resources/views/frontend/v2/...
```

In my config files I want to have a variable version, which will hold the active template version.

The problem is that now I need to use this variable in all Controllers and Views, which is a lot of work. I want to change the variable only in the Views. Does anybody have faced that situation and have a better solution for it ?

Comment: potentially you could have a service provider setup a namespace for the view so you could do something like `frontend::some.view` and it would resolve to your particular folder based on the configuration

Comment: thank you for your response, unfortunately i dont understand your idea. Can you explain it with more details or if you know an article, you can send me the link ?

Comment: sure, i will make an answer for you in a lil bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

I've added namespaces in app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php, in the boot method:

```
$this->app['view']->addNamespace('theme', base_path().'/resources/views/frontend/.config('version'));
```

Than I need in all Controllers and Views make some changes, but this is only one time.

In any Controller I changed from:

```
return view('frontend.partials.banner')->withBanner($banner);
```

to:

```
return view('theme::partials.banner')->withBanner($banner);
```

and in any view from:

```
@include('frontend.standing.partials.shorttable')
```

to:

```
@include('theme::standing.partials.shorttable')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to be able to switch the theme/design from an admin page, you can simply setup the path to your views in your `config/view.php` file:

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | View Storage Paths
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Most templating systems load templates from disk. Here you may specify
    | an array of paths that should be checked for your views. Of course
    | the usual Laravel view path has already been registered for you.
    |
    */

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
        resource_path('theme/v1/views'),
    ],
```

Views in `resources/theme/views/` will be loaded as well as the ones in the `resources/views` directory.

Beware of the order: the first path defined will have a higher priority if two files share the same name.

Another solution, to prevent file name collision, is to use namespaced views. In you `AppServiceProvider`, add this to the `boot()` method:

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(resource_path('theme2/views'), 'theme2');
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/packages#views

In both cases, you can use a variable in your configuration. For example, in your `config/app.php`:

```
return [
    // Leave the configuration and add:
    'theme' => 'v1',
];
```

Then, in `config/view.php`:

```
    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
        resource_path('theme/'.config('app.theme').'/views'),
    ],
```

If you want to use an environment variable (to have a different theme in local environment and production):

```
    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
        resource_path('theme/'.env('APP_THEME').'/views'),
    ],
```

and in your `.env`:

```
APP_THEME=v1
```